# WP Delete User Button missing

Tags: wordpress

We have a Wordpress installation with a lot of users. If we wanted to delete a user so far, it took a long time until the delete button appeared. Then the deletion always worked. But now the button doesn't appear anymore. I have the feeling it's because it always first goes through the 400,000 users and it's because of that. I'm using WP version 4.9.8

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if there are many users it is loading very long. then you can filter the users to be displayed like this:

```
add_action( 'load-users.php', function () {
  // Make sure the "action" is "delete".
  if ( 'delete' !== filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'action' ) ) {
    return;
  }

  add_filter( 'wp_dropdown_users_args', function ( $query_args, $args ) {
    if ( 'reassign_user' === $args[ 'name' ] ) {
      $query_args[ 'role' ] = 'administrator';
    }

    return $query_args;
  }, 10, 2 );
} );
```